# Use ZSH in hyperTM with powerlevel9k, but the right label is always outside the range of one line

Tags: terminal, themes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zshrc, hyperterminal

Recently I tried to use Linux on win10. I installed HyperTM, ZSH, Oh-My-ZSH, and the theme used the 'powerlevel9k'. After opening ZSH with HyperTM, my right label goes from one line to the next, as shown below.

[oh-my-zsh with powerlevel9k on HyperTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4erZd.png)

but my bash(window subsystem) is normal

[bash.exe for Ubuntu on win10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSnqn.png)

I tried to change the setting of '.zshrc' and searching for HyperTM setting may solve this error, but did not find about, does anyone would solve this problem? :(

I'm not sure if this question is about powerlevel9k or ZSH or HyperTM.
following is my setting of .zshrc and HyperTM.

[.zshrc]

```
source ~/.zplug/init.zsh
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
  export ZSH="/home/weichieh/.oh-my-zsh"
# Set name of the theme to load. Optionally, if you set this to "random"
# it'll load a random theme each time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
# See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes
# ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k"
   ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k"
# powerlevel9k 設定
# POWERLEVEL9K_MODE='awesome_patched'
POWERLEVEL9K_PROMPT_ADD_NEWLINE=true
POWERLEVEL9K_DISABLE_RPROMPT=false

ZLE_RPROMPT_INDENT=0
#command line 左邊想顯示的內容
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(context dir dir_writable vcs vi_mode newline)
#command line 右邊想顯示的內容
POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(status background_jobs history load time)

# Set list of themes to load
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random
# cause zsh load theme from this variable instead of
# looking in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# An empty array have no effect
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion. Case
# sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# The optional three formats: "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
HIST_STAMPS="yyyy-mm-dd"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(
  git
  zsh-syntax-highlighting
  zsh-docker-aliases
  zsh-completions
)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# ssh
# export SSH_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/rsa_id"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
autoload -U compinit && compinit
zplug load
```

[.hyper.js]

```
module.exports = {
  config: {
    // choose either `'stable'` for receiving highly polished,
    // or `'canary'` for less polished but more frequent updates
    updateChannel: 'stable',

    // default font size in pixels for all tabs
    fontSize: 15,

    // font family with optional fallbacks
    fontFamily: '"Monaco","DejaVu Sans Mono", Awesome, "Source Code Pro","Fira Code", Menlo, Consolas, "Lucida Console", monospace',

    // default font weight: 'normal' or 'bold'
    fontWeight: 'normal',

    // font weight for bold characters: 'normal' or 'bold'
    fontWeightBold: 'bold',

    // terminal cursor background color and opacity (hex, rgb, hsl, hsv, hwb or cmyk)
    cursorColor: 'rgba(248,28,229,0.8)',

    // terminal text color under BLOCK cursor
    cursorAccentColor: '#000',

    // `'BEAM'` for |, `'UNDERLINE'` for _, `'BLOCK'` for █
    cursorShape: 'BLOCK',

    // set to `true` (without backticks and without quotes) for blinking cursor
    cursorBlink: false,

    // color of the text
    foregroundColor: '#fff',

    // terminal background color
    // opacity is only supported on macOS
    backgroundColor: '#000',

    // terminal selection color
    selectionColor: 'rgba(248,28,229,0.3)',

    // border color (window, tabs)
    borderColor: '#333',

    // custom CSS to embed in the main window
    css: '',

    // custom CSS to embed in the terminal window
    termCSS: '',

    // if you're using a Linux setup which show native menus, set to false
    // default: `true` on Linux, `true` on Windows, ignored on macOS
    showHamburgerMenu: '',

    // set to `false` (without backticks and without quotes) if you want to hide the minimize, maximize and close buttons
    // additionally, set to `'left'` if you want them on the left, like in Ubuntu
    // default: `true` (without backticks and without quotes) on Windows and Linux, ignored on macOS
    showWindowControls: '',

    // custom padding (CSS format, i.e.: `top right bottom left`)
    padding: '12px 14px',

    // the full list. if you're going to provide the full color palette,
    // including the 6 x 6 color cubes and the grayscale map, just provide
    // an array here instead of a color map object
    colors: {
      black: '#000000',
      red: '#C51E14',
      green: '#1DC121',
      yellow: '#C7C329',
      blue: '#0A2FC4',
      magenta: '#C839C5',
      cyan: '#20C5C6',
      white: '#C7C7C7',
      lightBlack: '#686868',
      lightRed: '#FD6F6B',
      lightGreen: '#67F86F',
      lightYellow: '#FFFA72',
      lightBlue: '#6A76FB',
      lightMagenta: '#FD7CFC',
      lightCyan: '#68FDFE',
      lightWhite: '#FFFFFF',
    },

    // the shell to run when spawning a new session (i.e. /usr/local/bin/fish)
    // if left empty, your system's login shell will be used by default
    //
    // Windows
    // - Make sure to use a full path if the binary name doesn't work
    // - Remove `--login` in shellArgs
    //
    // Bash on Windows
    // - Example: `C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe`
    //
    // PowerShell on Windows
    // - Example: `C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe`
    shell: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe',

    // for setting shell arguments (i.e. for using interactive shellArgs: `['-i']`)
    // by default `['--login', '-i', '/c wsl']` will be used
    shellArgs: [],

    // for environment variables
    env: {},

    // set to `false` for no bell
    bell: 'SOUND',

    // if `true` (without backticks and without quotes), selected text will automatically be copied to the clipboard
    copyOnSelect: false,

    // if `true` (without backticks and without quotes), hyper will be set as the default protocol client for SSH
    defaultSSHApp: true,

    // if `true` (without backticks and without quotes), on right click selected text will be copied or pasted if no
    // selection is present (`true` by default on Windows and disables the context menu feature)
    // quickEdit: true,

    // URL to custom bell
    // bellSoundURL: 'http://example.com/bell.mp3',

    // for advanced config flags please refer to https://hyper.is/#cfg
  },

  // a list of plugins to fetch and install from npm
  // format: [@org/]project[#version]
  // examples:
  //   `hyperpower`
  //   `@company/project`
  //   `project#1.0.1`
  plugins: [
    'hyperfull'
  ],

  // in development, you can create a directory under
  // `~/.hyper_plugins/local/` and include it here
  // to load it and avoid it being `npm install`ed
  localPlugins: [],

  keymaps: {
    // Example
    // 'window:devtools': 'cmd+alt+o',
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out the ZLE_RPROMPT_INDENT. This is usually the cause for such problems. The right gap will be fixed with the next release of Powerlevel9k anyway :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, it didn't to solve the problem by uncomment it.
I'm very happy to hear this news and look forward to the next release....hoping it can really use in recent. : |